# How do you disable authentication entirely for Swagger 3.0.0 using the WebFluxConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, springfox

I apologize if I omit some important information since I'm not experienced with these libraries. Feel free to ask for them! :)

I'm using Spring Boot `2.3.2.RELEASE` with Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR6` and Springfox `3.0.0`. The security I am using is `spring-boot-starter-security`. Below are the relevant `pom.xml` dependencies:

**`pom.xml`**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using the following annotations on the `Application`:

- `@EnableWebFlux`
- `@EnableDiscoveryClient`
- `@SpringBootApplication`

Here is a sampling of my `SwaggerResourceProvider`:

```
return () -> Stream.of(
  swaggerResource("Commander", "/docs/commander", "1.0"),
  ...
  swaggerResource("Querier", "/docs/querier", "3.0")
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is my `SwaggerResource`:

```
private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location, String serviceHighestVersion) {
  SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
  swaggerResource.setName(name);
  swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
  swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(serviceHighestVersion);
  return swaggerResource;
}
```

Here is my `SecurityConfig`:

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    ServerHttpSecurity http_ = http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable();

    http_
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "favicon.ico"
        )
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .permitAll();
    return http_.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager() {
    return (authentication) -> {
      authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
      return Mono.just(authentication);
    };
  }
```

And lastly (I think) is the `WebFluxConfigurer`:

```
public class SwaggerUiWebFluxConfigurer implements WebFluxConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }

  @Bean
  public Docket restApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)
        .select()
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
  }

  @Bean
  UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
        .docExpansion(DocExpansion.LIST)
        .build();
  }

  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
        .title("Workflow Services")
        .description("Workflow Services API Description")
        .contact(
            new Contact(
                "My Team",
                "https://moo.com",
                "hello@there.com"))
        .version("1.0.0")
        .build();
  }
}
```

I go to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui and am forwarded to http://localhost:8080/login

[image: Unexpected Sign In page]

I would like to disable the security for only the swagger. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this,

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/swagger-ui",
            "/webjars/**");
}
```